# SLE5528 memory card command to read its' unique ID

Tags: c#, smartcard, apdu, winscard

I have ACR38U smart card reader and SLE5528 memory cards. I would like to know what is the HEX read command for SLE5528 memory cards to read it's unique ID (or serial number)? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is possible (the reader seems to support two-wire memory card protocol, even if not mentioning this explicitly), but you have to consult the reader documentation.  Memory cards like the 5528 don't understand APDUs, the conversion is done by the reader, and which APDUs trigger the functionality, varies.

The so-called *chip-coding* is contained in the first memory block.